# Join 3 tables with a single table

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, join

I need to join 3 tables with a primary table.

Primary Table - Monitor, 
Secondary Table - RafflePoint, RaffleCode, RaffleWinner

Attaching images below.

[Monitor Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DM34.png)

[RafflePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2PU2.png)

[RaffleCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XpAn.png)
[RaffleWinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gONBJ.png)

My code looks something like this.

**raffleStatus.js**

```
MonitorModel.findOne({
  where: {
    id: monitor.id
  },
  include: [
      {
        model: MonitorRafflePoints,
        where:{
          monitor_id: monitor.id, 
          month: currentUTCTime
        }
      }
      ,{
        model: MonitorRaffleCode,
        where: {
          monitor_id : monitor.id, 
          created_at : { $between: [ startOfMonth, endOfMonth ] }
        }
      }
      ,{
        model: RaffleWinnersModel,
        where: {
          monitor_id: monitor.id,
          date : { $between: [ startOfMonth, endOfMonth ] }
        }
      }
  ]
})
.then(function(monitor){

    // monitor = JSON.stringify(monitor);
    console.log('After stringify ----> ', typeof (monitor)); 

    if(monitor){
      console.log(' <---- Inside If ----> ', monitor)
      monitor.MonitorRafflePoints.forEach(function(points){
        monitorPoint = points;
      });
      console.log('Monitor Raffle Points ----> ',monitorPoint);

       monitor.MonitorRaffleCodes.forEach(function(codes){
         monitorCodes = codes;
       });

       monitor.MonitorWinner.forEach(function(winners){
         monitorWinner = winners;
       });
      return getLastWinnerDetails();
    }else{
      console.log(' <---- Inside Else ---->', monitor);

      monitorPoint = JSON.stringify(monitor.MonitorRafflePoints);
      monitorCodes = JSON.stringify(monitor.MonitorRaffleCodes);
      monitorWinner = JSON.stringify(monitor.RaffleWinners);
      return getLastWinnerDetails();
    }
}).then(function(winner){
     var response  = {};
       console.log('Last Response ----->',response);
     return res.json(response);
})
```

The association for this tables are as follows.

**index.js**

```
 // Raffle relations with Monitor
db.Monitor.hasMany(db.MonitorRafflePoints, {foreignKey: 
'monitor_id'});
// db.Monitor.belongsTo(db.MonitorRafflePoints, {foreignKey: 
'monitor_id'});
db.MonitorRafflePoints.belongsTo(db.Monitor, {foreignKey: 
'monitor_id'});
db.Monitor.hasMany(db.MonitorRaffleCode, {foreignKey: 
'monitor_id'});
db.MonitorRaffleCode.belongsTo(db.Monitor, {foreignKey: 
'monitor_id'});
db.Monitor.hasMany(db.RaffleWinners, {foreignKey: 'monitor_id'});
db.RaffleWinners.belongsTo(db.Monitor, {foreignKey: 
'monitor_id'});
db.MonitorRafflePoints.hasMany(db.MonitorRaffleCode, {foreignKey: 
'monitor_id'});
// db.MonitorRaffleCode.belongsTo(db.MonitorRafflePoints, 
{foreignKey: 'monitor_id'});
```

When ever i run this code i seem to get en error instead of getting the result.

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpSiE.png)

What am i doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Re-Edit - 
Upon successfully getting a Monitor_id from the Monitor table it should look for MonitorRafflePoint with the same Monitor_id in the RafflePoint table, when found then next it should look for RaffleCode with the same monitor_id in the RaffleCode table. 
Next it should fetch the rafflewinner from the RaffleWinner table.

Lastly to get the LastWinnerDetails i have written a small function.

**raffleStatus.js**

**getLastWinnerDetails function**

```
var getLastWinnerDetails = function(){
  return RaffleWinnersModel.find({
    include : [{
      model : MonitorModel,
      include : [{
        model : PatientModel,
     }]
  }],
  limit: 1,
   order: [ [ 'date', 'DESC' ]]
   });
}
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: yes thank you phil , i have tried to provide as much information as possible

Comment: You have not acted on my comments at all. A [mre] is *required* for debugging questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: You just edited your post. But--see my last comment.

Comment: sure i will provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: There is no RaffleWinners monitor_id matching Monitor. So findOne returns what?

Comment: I know that. The question was rhetorical. I just said, no such id exists.

Comment: It will return null for Monitor.RaffleWinners in the findOne if there is no data with the monitor_id in the table RaffleWinners.

Comment: I just told you twice that "there is no data with the monitor_id in the table RaffleWinners". Now I have told you 3 times.

Comment: correct phil , appreciate you support but, the question is - if a Monitor is found and then for that monitor some monitorRafflePoint if exist it should come in Monitor.MonitorRafflePoints which is not itself coming inspite of the data being available in the MonitorRafflePoints table.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will reach the else condition (Inside Else) only when `monitor` is null. You are getting this error at `monitorPoint = JSON.stringify(monitor.MonitorRafflePoints);`

So, you can't access `monitor.MonitorRafflePoints` as `monitor` is null.

Comment: Yes exactly , but i am checking with a valid monitorId which exist in the table. Why doesnt it retrieves all the data.